# Como conseguir a URL ou âncora em uma One-page

Tags: html

Estou desenvolvendo uma One-page, e gostaria, que cada vez que o cliente esteja em uma sessão, ele muda o endereço de www.teste.com.br para www.teste.com.br/depoimentos ou www.teste.com.br#depoimentos, tanto faz.

Pensei em usar âncoras, mas não sei se é o indicado, pois isso é interessante também para a indexação do site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o link assim:

```
<a href="#depoimentos">Depoimentos</a>
```

E você marca a posição na pagina assim:

```
<a id="depoimentos"></a>
```

Assim quando alguém clicar no link `Depoimentos` a rolagem da pagina levara para o elemento `<a id="depoimentos"></a>`.

Comment: Âncora, bem como eu imaginava. E o Google indexa isso, será?

Comment: Sim, âncora é um link normal, que também informa uma posição especifica da página de destino. Neste caso a pagina destino é a mesma página em que o link se encontra.